# Returning a list from a POST request in Spring using AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, spring, google-app-engine, jackson

I currently have a POST request on a page to retrieve a list of lessons.

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { 
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': '/search/request',
    'data': JSON.stringify(data),
    'dataType': 'json'
});
```

The corresponding method in the controller returns a list of lessons:

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
public class SearchController {
    // Some other methods

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/request",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Lesson> search_lessons(@CookieValue("token") String token, @RequestBody SearchQuery query) {
        try {
            // Grab the user.

            // TODO: Implement search logic.
            List<Lesson> searchedLessons = lessonService.get_main_lessons_by_user(user);
            System.out.println(searchedLessons.size());
            return searchedLessons;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When I make the request, it hits the `System.out.println(searchedLessons.size());`, so I know the list is being populated. However, making the AJAX call results in a 500 error, and no exceptions are thrown. How do I get Spring to return this list?

EDIT: This is the structure of a `Lesson`

```
package com.dolphinblue.models;

import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Index;

import java.util.*;
/**
 * Created by FreddyEstevez on 3/21/17.
 * Represent model for lessons
 */
@Entity
public class Lesson implements Comparable<Lesson>{

    @Id private Long lesson_id;
    private Long index;
    private String title;
    @Index private String user_id; //user who is working on the lesson
    @Index private String creator_id; //user who created the lesson
    private List<Key<Task>> tasks; //holds lists of tasks ids for this lesson
    private double percent_complete; // Hold the percent of task the user has completed
    @Index private boolean shared;
    @Index private  boolean site_owned;
    private Key<Lesson> original_lesson;
    private String description;
    private int rating;
    //Date when lesson was last edited or changed.
    private Date last_edited;
    //Date when this lesson was last access by user working on it
    private Date last_accessed;
```

`

Comment: Do you have jackson on the classpath? What is the structure of a Lesson?
 Is there any lazy loading that might be occuring? Are you seeing anything logged? Have you tried adding a exception handler?

Comment: Jackson is on the classpath, as it does successfully serialize the `SearchQuery` object. Edited comment to add the structure of a lesson. Given that it hints the print statement right before the return statement, the searchedLessons are already loaded before it returns. Nothing is being logged, and the method already contains exception handling.

Comment: That catch block will not catch an exception that occurs during serialization of the return which I suspect is happening. Is tasks or original_lesson lazy loaded?

Comment: I guess they may have been, because getting rid of those fields resulted in a successful serialization. I don't think Jackson is capable of serializing Objectify keys.

Answer (score 0):

So, getting rid of any fields with Objectify Keys allowed the object to serialize.